# Obtener palabra y las veces que se repite

Tags: java, condiciones, consola

Tengo una cadena de texto, y la estoy pasando a ser un array para poder recorrer la cadena, y luego buscar cuales fueron las palabras que se repitieron mas de 2 veces, ya tengo las palabras que se repiten mas de 2 veces, pero quisiera que solo se impriman una vez y con su respectivo valor de las veces que se repitieron.

```
    int length = this.cadena.split(" ").length;
    String[] listWord = new String[length];
    listWord = this.cadena.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    String word;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        word = listWord[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (listWord[j].equals(word)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count >= 2) {
           System.out.println(listWord[i] + " " + count);
        } else {
           //System.out.println(listWord[i] + " " + count);
        }

        System.out.println(listWord[i]);
        count = 0;
     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int length = this.cadena.split(" ").length;
String[] listWord;
listWord = this.cadena.toLowerCase().split(" ");


// 1.Crear un Set, el Set no permite valores duplicados
// se convierte listWord en una lista para usarlo de argumento
// en el constructor del Set
Set<String> palabras = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(listWord));

// 2. Se recorre el Set, no contiene palabras repetidas
for(String word : palabras){

    // la lógica es la misma de antes

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        if (listWord[j].equals(word)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
        System.out.println(word + " " + count);
    } else {
        //System.out.println(listWord[i] + " " + count);
    }

    count = 0;

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfecto.